# Как запустить python скрипт в фоне?

Tags: python

Недавно возникла нужда запускать скрип при запуске ПК и делать его невидимым(вернее видимым при анализе, например в диспечере задач, но не видимом в хотбаре). И если с запуском пк решение было найдено, то с запуском скрипта в фоне разобраться никак не смог. Прошу о помощи!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Создайте файл скрипта, который вы хотите запускать (например, myscript.py).
- Создайте файл batch-скрипта, который запустит ваш Python скрипт в фоновом режиме.

  `@echo off`

  `start /MIN pythonw.exe "C:\path\to\your\script.py"`
- Поместите ваш batch-файл в папку автозапуска Windows

Comment: Благодарю за ответ!

Comment: @PereStack , если ответ помог Вам, тогда нажмите на галку возле ответа)

Answer (score 2):

Можно просто подмахнуть расширение скрипта с `.py` на `.pyw` и скрипт запустится без консоли.